# owl carousel 2 dynamic height

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

i'm trying to make a carousel width owl carousel 2. My slides height are diferent. But i have expand & collpase inside of each slide and that means that autoheight will mess up the height when i open the expand/collapse. if i remove the autoheight, the height of the carousel moves with the expand & collapse but the height of the slides will be the same as the heighest slide and this means that i will have some blank spaces in sme of them. How can i get around this?

Please help. Tks in advance.

With autoheight i tried this:

```
$('.exp-coll .title').on('click', function() {
    var height = $('.exp-coll').height();
    if($(this).next().hasClass('active')) {
        var plus = ($(this).height());
    }
    else {
        var plus = -($(this).height());
    }
    var h = height+plus;
    $('.owl-height').animate({height: h}, 300);
});
```

this almost works but not perfect

Comment: never mind.... Got it to work =)